# Can MAGMA compute pullbacks of $kG$-modules?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, computational-mathematics, magma-cas

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p>0$ such that $p\mid |G|$.

Let $M_1, M_2$ and $M_3$ be finitely generated $kG$-modules.

I read in the MAGMA online manual that MAGMA can compute pullbacks, but the function provided there works for the input types ModAlg and ModAlgFldElt, respectively.

Unfortunately, I was not able to let MAGMA compute a pullback when given two $kG$ homomorphisms $f: M_1\rightarrow M_3$ and $g: M_2\rightarrow M_3$.

Therefore, I'd like to ask:

> Can MAGMA compute pullbacks of $kG$-modules?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT (April 7th 2020):**

I tried the following, but got an error message.

```
> G:=Alt(4);
> K:=GF(4);
> PIMs:=ProjectiveIndecomposableModules(G,K);
> P1:=PIMs[1];
> P2:=PIMs[2];
> P3:=PIMs[3];
> 
> 
> h:=Random(GHom(P1,P3));
> h;
[    1 K.1^2   K.1     0]
[K.1^2     1     1 K.1^2]
[  K.1     0 K.1^2     1]
[    0   K.1     0   K.1]
> 
> 
> k:=Random(GHom(P2,P3));
> k;
[K.1^2 K.1^2     1     1]
[    1 K.1^2 K.1^2   K.1]
[  K.1 K.1^2     0 K.1^2]
[    1 K.1^2 K.1^2   K.1]
> 
> M,i,j,p,q:=DirectSum(P1,P2);
> h*p;

>> h*p;
    ^
Runtime error in '*': Bad argument types
Argument types given: ModMatGrpElt[FldFin], Map[ModGrp, ModGrp]
```

Comment: Can't you just define it using its definition as the kernel of the difference between the composite  maps $M_1 \oplus M_2 \to M_3$ induced by $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I edited the question. Is it possible to transform the type of the morphism $h$ from  ModMatGrpElt[FldFin] to Map[ModGrp, ModGrp]?

Comment: I don't know why that doesn't work - type clashes are often an irritating problem in Magma. You can define the composite directly with  hom< M -> P1 | [p(h(M.i)): i in [1..Ngens(M)]] >;

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. So > hom_new:=hom< M -> P3 | [h(p(M.i))-k(q(M.i)): i in [1..Ngens(M)]] >;  ${}$  ${}$  ${}$  ${}$  ${}$  ${}$  ${}$  ${}$                   > PB:=Kernel(hom_new); gave me a GModule which should be the pullback. Is this correct?